# Automapper, complex property and inheritance

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to get AutoMapper work and really stuck with a simple task. I have a complex type defined in User entity:

```
[ComplexType]
public class CustomerProfile
{
    public string       FirstName                { get; set; }
    public string       LastName                 { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class User
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Email { get; get; }
    public CustomerProfile CustomerProfile { get; set; }
}
```

And I have view model like that:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : CustomerProfile
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So I just have all of the CustomerProfile properties in view model plus Email.

I want to map User to CustomerViewModel. I tried everything but didn't succeed actually. Even this code doesn't work:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerProfile, CustomerViewModel>();
```

Automapper just refuses to map anything.

How it could be mapped? Thanks.

Comment: what is it that "doesn't work" and how does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ConstructUsing` to create a `CustomerViewModel` from a `User` instance. Then the remaining properties (e.g., `Email`) will be mapped automatically by AutoMapper as long as the names match:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerProfile, CustomerViewModel>();

Mapper.CreateMap<User, CustomerViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(src.CustomerProfile));
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/RzpD4z

---

*Update*

To make `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` pass, you need to ignore the properties that you've mapped manually. You also need to ignore the `Email` property on `CustomerViewModel` from the `CustomerProfile` → `CustomerViewModel` mapping, since that will be taken care of by the `User` → `CustomerViewModel` mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerProfile, CustomerViewModel>()
    // Ignore Email since it's mapped by the User to CustomerViewModel mapping.
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<User, CustomerViewModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(src.CustomerProfile))
    // Ignore FirstName/LastName since they're mapped above using ConstructUsing.
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

**Updated example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/KitDiC

Comment: @RomanPushkin: Yup, you need to ignore the properties that you're mapping with the `ConstructUsing` call. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll update my answer.